# Replace textbox with drop down list

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, struts2, struts

```
<s:select name="searchCriteria"
            headerValue="Select Criteria"
            list="#{'userName':'User Name','email':'Email','status':'Status','firmName':'Firm Name','firstName':'First Name',
            'middleName':'Middle Name','lastName':'Last Name'}"
              ></s:select>

<s:textfield name="searchField" size="50" />
```

I have a dropdown list which  allows me to search users by a search criteria..Howeveer when the user selects search by firm name. I want to replace the textbox with a drop down list(Displaying available firms).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the text box in a div and then add an event on when user makes the required selection you could do something like

```
$('div').empty().html('<s: select ... ');
```

Comment: The problem is s:select is a struts2 tag..and a browser cannot process a struts2 tag

Comment: try pre creating the element then and hiding it until the user selects and then showing it when the selection is made and hiding the text box field with out removing anything from the page

Answer (score 0):

People didn't accept my edit over Alex_B (¬¬' I was just encoding what Alex_B said in comments) so I put this new answer:

*Wrap the text box in a div and then add an event on when user makes the required selection you could do something like*

```
$('#select_id').show();
$('#textbox_id').hide();
```

*And the jsp:*

```
<s:select id="first_select" ... ></s:select>

<s:select id="select_id" ...></s:select>
<s:textfield id="textbox_id" .../>
```